# Canvas Larger Than Screen

Tags: android

I am drawing a grid and I want it to be larger than the screen size so that a user can drag the screen left/right/up/down to get to the rest of the grid.

What is the best way to do that?  I've tried drawing a larger bitmap to the canvas, but didn't get anywhere.

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas);

       Paint paint = new Paint();
       paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
       paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

       Bitmap testBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1000, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       canvas.drawBitmap(testBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

       canvas.drawPaint(paint);

       //other grid drawing code here
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the View's scrollBy() method in the onTouch method of the Activity.  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the canvas.translate(x, y) method. That will adjust the origin for your canvas in relation to the screen. So canvas.translate(10, 10) will make you canvas origin (0, 0) be at the point of (10, 10) on the screen. Use a negative translation to scroll the screen.

Comment: This means i would need to re-draw everything that I currently have on the screen, no?

Comment: Shouldn't, it just re positions the canvas, everything drawn on the canvas is relative to the canvas position, that said if it makes things off having the canvas re positioned then yes, you would have to compensate for the translation.